403 Error When Uploading Files Larger Than ~10KB to S3:B from Next.js Deployed on CloudFront
I'm working on a project where I deployed a Next.js application on CloudFront, which serves static files from an S3 bucket (S3:A). My application also allows users to upload files to a different S3 bucket (S3:B).
Setup Details:

Frontend: Next.js, hosted on CloudFront with S3:A for static assets.
Backend: FastAPI, using boto3 for S3 operations.
Local Testing: The application works perfectly locally and on a Jenkins test server, successfully uploading files up to 2GB.
Production Issue: In production, files smaller than ~10KB can be uploaded successfully, but files larger than ~10KB (e.g., an HTML file as small as 1KB) fail with a 403 Forbidden error.

403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.


What I've Tried:

Verified S3 bucket policies for S3:B to ensure permissions allow uploads.
Verified CloudFront and S3 configurations for headers and caching settings.
Confirmed that CORS settings on S3:B allow file uploads via PUT and POST.
Ensured IAM roles and policies for the application are properly configured to allow s3:PutObject.
Tried uploading directly using AWS CLI, which worked as expected, confirming the bucket configuration is not the issue.


What I Need Help With:

Why might the application fail to upload files larger than ~10KB in production but work locally?
Are there specific CloudFront, S3, or FastAPI configurations that could cause such size-based restrictions?


I'm a beginner with basic knowledge of S3 and CloudFront, so I might have missed something fundamental. Any help or guidance is appreciated.
